# How to use ModelingToolkit.jl to create variables dynamically

Tags: julia, differentialequations.jl

The main problem is that my variables would be determined only after running the codes (because the number of variables is not fixed).

In old version ModelingToolkit.jl, I used the following codes to generate a variable.

```
my_var = Variable(Symbol(name))(t)  # name is a string
```

However, it can’t work in the latest version. Here is the error.

```
ERROR: Sym name is not callable. Use @syms name(var1, var2,...) to create it as a callable.
```

I've checked SymbolicUtils.jl but didn't find other usages. How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `@variables` macro to create symbolic variables at runtime as well. The `$` operator interpolates the runtime value.

```
julia> using ModelingToolkit

julia> z = :abc;

julia> k = @variables $z
1-element Vector{Num}:
 abc

julia> k[1]
abc
```

Comment: Oh, it can be interpolated! Thank you!